# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot now detect 2nd monitor

Tags: 22.04, monitor

Ubuntu 22.04 was working perfectly with 2 monitors, since last weekend I connected one to windows laptop and configured 1 display on Ubuntu. Now whatever I do I cannot get back to 2 monitors, it just doesnt detect the 2nd monitor... I am so confused. My video card is RTX 3060.

I also discovered that it doesnt find the speakers, neither the mic. No sound. Says dummy output.

I guess I have nothing else than to try to reinstall the ubuntu. Any easiest suggestion about this please?

Further I saw that exfat is not working now, and when I try to install 22.04 mouse is not working... and the install hangs...

22.04 is a jewel of a program, what happened to the usual Ubuntu fellows??

Comment: The question @Maxxx has is: 'In settings/screen display, can you see the 2nd monitor icon in the top?'.

Comment: No Max, I cannot see. Thank you so much for your interest and kind help.